# Large Scale Social Network Analysis for Hypergraphs

Tags: giraph, sna, hypergraph

I have been trying to implement large scale social network analysis for hypergraphs. But Apache Giraph allows only simple graphs and Multigraphs. II couldn't find any suitable method to implement Large Scale SNA in Hypergraphs. Please suggest me suitable methods.

Comment: can you be more explicit about what kinds of analysis you want to do with the hypergraphs, and how large is 'Large Scale'?

Answer (score -1):

R package called "network" should be able to handle this. I'm currently looking into using igraph as well

Comment: Please post more details